# Visibility of selected menu background color can be improved in activity tab

Tags: feature-request, design, activity

In the Activity tab, if I select any one of the menu items (such as Summary, Answers, Questions ...), the background color of the selected menu has less visibility. When I hover over on any of the other menu item, the background color has more visibility compared with the selected menu.

For example, here I selected [Activity -> Summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) menu and hover the next menu "Answers", please refer the screenshot below. Can the selected menu's background color be improved for more visibility?

[image: Summary menu]